Fetch employee id from from job description properties .NET 8
I am trying to fetch Employee ID field from Azure EntraId. More details about issues shown here:

In this screenshot, you can see the employee id field I'm trying to fetch using MS Graph client, but I'm getting null every time I try:

Here's my code used for fetching data via the graph client:
private static GraphServiceClient GetGraphClient(string clientId, string tenantId, string clientSecret)
{
    // Set up the client credential authentication provider
    var confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
            .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
            .WithAuthority(new Uri($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}"))
            .Build();

    var authProvider = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);

    // Create and return the GraphServiceClient with the authentication provider
    return new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
}

Here's the code get the employee:
var result = await graphClient.Users
                        .GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
                            {
                               requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Filter = $"displayname eq '{User.Mail}'";
                               requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Select = ["employeeId", "EmployeeID", "EMP_ID"];
                            });

I'm getting all other basic details from claims.
Please help me get the employee id as well.

Are you trying to fetch employee id of particular user or users from your tenant? Could you share your complete code and edit the question?

Is this below solution works for you ?

Initially, Registered Single-Tenant Microsoft Entra ID Application , Added and Granted Application type User.Read.All API Permission:

I created one test user as testUser1 and configured employeeId and mail.
In Portal, Ensure that Employee ID should not be null in Properties, and should exist like below:

Use below modified code, To get a employee_ID of particular User:
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Azure.Identity; // For ClientSecretCredential
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class GraphClientExample
{
    private static GraphServiceClient GetGraphClient(string clientId, string tenantId, string clientSecret)
    {
        // Use ClientSecretCredential for authentication
        var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);

        // Return the GraphServiceClient using ClientSecretCredential
        return new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential);
    }

    public static async Task FetchEmployee(string clientId, string tenantId, string clientSecret, string userMail)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userMail))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("User mail is null or empty.");
            return;
        }

        // Initialize Graph client
        var graphClient = GetGraphClient(clientId, tenantId, clientSecret);

        try
        {
            // Fetch the user details
            var result = await graphClient.Users
                .GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
                {
                    // Apply filter and select query
                    requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Filter = $"mail eq '{userMail}'";
                    requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Select = new[] { "id", "displayName", "mail", "employeeId" };
                });

            // Check if any users are found
            if (result?.Value != null && result.Value.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var user in result.Value)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"User Found: {user.DisplayName}, ID:{user.Id}, Email: {user.Mail}, Employee ID: { user.EmployeeId}");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No matching user found.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }

    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Replace these with your app registration details
        string clientId = "<YOUR CLIENT ID";
        string tenantId = "YOUR TENANAT ID";
        string clientSecret = "YOUR CLIENT SECRET";
        string userMail = "<YOUR TEST USER EMAIL SEARCH>"; // Email to search

        await FetchEmployee(clientId, tenantId, clientSecret, userMail);
    }
}


Response:

